# Nodejs: How can i simply get the request body using express4?

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

Now that express is not shipped anymore with middleware that fills the `req.body` variable i am fighting to get `req.body` filled again.
I am sending a POST request to `/xyz/:object/feedback`.

here my code:

```
app.post('/xyz/:object/feedback', function(req, res)
{
    console.log('Feedback received.');

    console.log('Body: ', req.body); // is not available :(

    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf8');
    res.send(result ? JSON.stringify(req.body) : err);
});
```

I tried to use body-parser already, but "Feedback received." never got logged to my console. So something seems to get stuck here:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

**How can i get `req.body` filled?** (i need some working code)

Comment: The problem can be in your path `/xyz/:object/feedback`. Do you send a post request to correct url? Also try this `app.use(bodyParser())` instead of passing whole module.

Comment: yes, i send a post request to the correct url (i can see the debug output) when i don't use bodyParse

Comment: And what about `app.use(bodyParser())`? This is possibly the problem.

Comment: as i said: "I tried to use body-parser already, but "Feedback received." never got logged to my console. So something seems to get stuck here"

Comment: you use app.use(bodyParser), not app.use(bodyParser())

Comment: that's it!!!!!! post this as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the whole module to the `use` method not the required instance.

Instead of this:

```
app.use(bodyParser);
```

do

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `app.use(bodyParser())`.

`bodyParser()` will return a function with what to use. `bodyParser` on its own is an invalid function for Express.

Comment: can i see an example?

Comment: plagiat see comments of  0101

Comment: @NikolayLukyanchuk i recognized the problem on my own, it's not my fault 0101 only posted a comment.

Comment: @Thariama I gave an example. Add the parentheses to call the function.